# Why are link and script tags not typed as elements?

Tags: javascript, types

I thought that every element returned from `document.getElementById` or `document.createElement` was in fact some version of a dom element, and that version could be found using `typeof`. However, I recently discovered this is not the case when I tried to do that to `script` and `link` tags.

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/TLsR3/)***

html

```
<link id="l">
<script id="s">
```

js

```
var l = document.getElementById("l");
console.log(typeof l);//"object"
var s = document.getElementById("s");
console.log(typeof s);//"object"
var li = document.createElement("link");
console.log(typeof li);//"object"
var sc = document.createElement("script");
console.log(typeof sc);//"object"
```

Why are these elements typed as objects?

Comment: `typeof` doesn't return "element" for anything.

Comment: @j08691 - I must have been mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are elements, and you get the same result than for other types of elements.

Try this :

```
var li = document.createElement("link");
console.log(li instanceof HTMLElement);
```

It logs `true` as the link is an instance of [HTMLLinkElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLLinkElement) which is a specialization of `HTMLElement`.

But [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) simply returns `"object"` for most objects ("any other object").

You can get the type of the object using [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) :

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(li));
```

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` is specifically for native JavaScript objects. There's a very limited set of values that `typeof` will return.

The `"object"` response is basically for any object, or `null` *(which is actually not an object... go figure)*. You'll likely get the same response from any type of Element, not just `script` and `link`.

You can use `instanceof` to see if the element is an intstance of the `Element` constructor's prototype.

```
console.log(l instanceof Element); // true
```

---

Note that objects like elements and their constructors are host objects. They sometimes play by different rules from native JavaScript objects, so there could be quirks here and there to deal with when testing their types.